# Why does Java file write consume CPU?

Tags: java, queue, bufferedwriter

I am writing data to file using a queue on a separate thread, but the process consumes around 25% of CPU, as shown in this test main.

Is there something I can do to resolve this issue?

Perhaps I should be using flush() somewhere?

The test shows the main method start and run the queue thread and then send created data to it. The queue thread writes the data to a BufferedWriter which handles writing the data to a file.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import uk.co.moonsit.utils.timing.Time;

public class OutputFloatQueueReceiver extends Thread {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(OutputFloatQueueReceiver.class.getName());

private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<List<Float>> queue = null;
private boolean running = true;
private final BufferedWriter outputWriter;
private int ctr = 0;

private final int LIMIT = 1000;

public OutputFloatQueueReceiver(String outputFile, String header, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<List<Float>> q) throws IOException {

    queue = q;

    File f = new File(outputFile);
    FileWriter fstream = null;
    if (!f.exists()) {
        try {
            f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            if (!f.createNewFile()) {
                throw new IOException("Exception when trying to create file " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            fstream = new FileWriter(outputFile, false);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(ControlHierarchy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new IOException("Exception when trying to create file " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    fstream = new FileWriter(outputFile, true);
    outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    outputWriter.append(header);

}

public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (running) {
        while (queue.peek() != null) {
            if (ctr++ % LIMIT == 0) {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Output Queue size = {0} '{'ctr={1}'}'", new Object[]{queue.size(), ctr});
            }

            List<Float> list = queue.poll();
            if (list == null) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                StringBuilder sbline = new StringBuilder();
                Time t = new Time(list.get(0));
                sbline.append(t.HMSS()).append(",");
                for (Float f : list) {
                    sbline.append(f).append(",");
                }
                sbline.append("\n");
                outputWriter.write(sbline.toString());

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOG.info(ex.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (outputWriter != null) {
        try {
            outputWriter.close();
            LOG.info("Closed outputWriter");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OutputFloatQueueReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        String outputFile = "c:\\tmp\\qtest.csv";
        File f = new File(outputFile);
        f.delete();

        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
        header.append("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9");
        header.append("\n");
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<List<Float>> outputQueue = null;

        OutputFloatQueueReceiver outputQueueReceiver = null;
        outputQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        outputQueueReceiver = new OutputFloatQueueReceiver(outputFile, header.toString(), outputQueue);
        outputQueueReceiver.start();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
            List<Float> list = new ArrayList<>();

            //list.set(0, (float) i); // causes exception
            list.add((float) i);
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                list.add((float) j);
            }

            outputQueue.add(list);                                
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OutputFloatQueueReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        outputQueueReceiver.setRunning(false);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OutputFloatQueueReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried running this through a profiler to see what is actually consuming this much CPU?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. All the `File.delete()` and `File.createNewFile()` calls are a complete waste of time here. `new FileWriter(...)` already has to do all that, in the OS. You are forcing it all to happen twice. And then if the file doesn't exist, which is already a redundant test, you are (a) creating it, (b) recreating it in non-append mode, (c) failing to close it, (d) leaking it, and (e) *re*-re-creating it in append mode. Don't write code like this. Give the file system some credit. It already knows what to do.

Comment: In other words the entire block starting with the `f.exists()` test can be deleted without altering the semantics of your application in any way, except to increase its efficiency.

Comment: @EJP Yes, that was a bit messy, didn't notice I'd created fstream twice. Did as you advised, though needed to retain mkdirs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is the reason while your code is using so much CPU:

```
while (running) {
    while (queue.peek() != null) {
        // logging
        List<Float> list = queue.poll();
        if (list == null) {
            continue;
        }
        // do stuff with list
    }
}
```

Basically, your code is busy-waiting, repeatedly "peeking" until a queue entry becomes available.  It is probably spinning there in a tight loop.

You should replace your queue class with a `BlockingQueue`, and simply use `take()` ... like this:

```
while (running) {
    List<Float> list = queue.take();
    // do stuff with list
}
```

The `take()` call block indefinitely, only returning once there is an element available, and returning that element as the result.  If blocking indefinitely is a problem, you could either use `poll(...)` with a timeout, or you could arrange that some other thread interrupts the thread that is blocked.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do it. I think I'd considered BlockingQueue but had thought a poll() would block the put(), but that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Agreed ... that that wouldn't make sense.